# Node Editor: Custom Label Shortcut

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, workflow, shortcut

I want to create a keyboard shortcut to quickly label a selected node.

The ideal shortcut would bring up a text box to show input, and then pressing Enter would assign the text as a Custom Label.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 2.81, Node labels are now quickly renamed with the hotkey **F2**.

Additionally, **Ctrl F2** opens a Batch Rename window for bulk editing. These shortcuts also work with Objects, Bones, and Collections.

(Note: I originally posted this question in the context of version 2.79)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do precisely what you want, but SHIFT-ALT-L will bring up a dialog that allows you to quickly modify the label
(Not sure if this requires Node Wrangler or not. If it does, simply enable Node Wrangler in user preference -> Add Ons.)

Comment: Yes that is from node wrangler.

Comment: Complementing the answer, using the Node Wrangler addon, if the label previously has a custom name, first use Alt L to clear the name, and then use Shift Alt L to give a new name (in the Add to Beginning field).